# Does the boundedness of partial derivatives imply continuity?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose that the partial derivatives of a given  function $f$ are bounded.

Does this imply that the given function is continuous?

#### Remark

For functions of one variable this is true, because every differentiable function is continuous.  But in several variables there are discontinuous functions which have partial derivatives everywhere, like $xy/(x^2+y^2)$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $f:V=(x_0 -h ,x_0 +h)\times (y_0-h ,y_0 +h)\to \mathbb{R},$$h>0$ be a function of two variables. Suppose that there exists $M>0$ such that $$\sup_{(u,w)\in V}\max\left\{\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} (u,v)\right| ,\left|\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} (u,v)\right|\right\} \leq M$$
then $f$ is continuous at $(x_0 ,y_0 ).$

To see this , take any $(\sigma , \xi )\in V$ then using Lagrange mean value theorem we have: $$|f(x_0 , y_0 )- f(\sigma , \xi ) |\leq |f(x_0 , y_0 ) -f(x_0 , \xi )|+|f(x_0 , \xi ) -f(\sigma , \xi )| \leq M(|y_0 -\xi|+|x_0 -\sigma |)$$ which implies continuity at $(x_0 ,y_0 ).$